# How does @Transactional isolation work without locking?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa

Figured out from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831350/10894456
`@Transactional` doesn't lock rows triggered on entities which are used inside `@Transactional` methods.

And one need to use either optimistic ( `@Version` annotation in Entities) or pessimistic ( `@Lock` in repositary methods) explicit directives out of the `@Transactional` method.

The question is: how does isolation work on `@Transactional` methods in the face of any locks absence?
e.g.

```
@Service
public class AService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository1 repository1;

    @Autowired
    private Repository2 repository2;

    @Autowired
    private Repository3 repository3;

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public Result getResult(Long id) {
        Entity1 e1 = repository1.findById(id);
        Entity2 e2 = repository2.findById(id);
        Entity3 e3 = repository3.findById(id);
        e1.setField(doSomeLogic(...)));
        e2.setField(doSomeLogic(...)));
        e3.setField(doSomeLogic(...)));
        repository1.save(e1);
        repository2.save(e2);
        repository3.save(e3);
        return Result.combine(e1,e2,e3);
    }
}
```

What is guaranteed by using

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

?
And how do this guarantees work without any locking?

Comment: The isolation is achieved by the database itself, not by JPA or Spring. And the database internally uses locks. You'd need to read the documentation of your database to if and how it supports the serializable isolation level.

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right, (a)Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) is here for purpose. What I still haven't got: how (a)Transactional annotation interacts with mentioned optimistic and pessimistic locks? Do I still jeopardize to lost update or not if I don't use explicit locks ( (a)Lock or (a)Version)  ? ( I'm using (a) here instead of @ due to it's only one symbol allowed here in comments)

Comment: With a high enough Isolation level you can prevent lost updates assuming the database supports it. And I don't think SERIALIZABLE can be achieved without locks.

Comment: @JensSchauder What I discovered while browsing: DB locks ( shared/exclusive) are not the same JPA locks ( (a)Version/(a)Lock) so yes of course all DB transactions use DB locks (shared/exclusive). No need to use JPA locks, isolation guaranteed by Transactional annotation. So the question now: why do we need JPA locks, if everything is fine with using Transactional annotation?

Comment: The answer is: because you might want finer-grained control over locks *in addition to* what your database (with its isolation level settings) does by default. Performance tweaking is one reason for that. Performance is, after all, the only reason why we don't all just use the serializable isolation level everywhere